# How to change html blocks at vuejs parent app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I need recommendation about "the right way" of vuejs layout structure.

I have header, which is the same for whole app but it (header) has one block that changes, depended on which child app I have. Currently it's a parent App.

What is the best solution for that?

- multiple parent App
- use header as a component with a slot
- any better way ?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking but this reminded me of the scenario described by https://michaelnthiessen.com/advanced-vue-controlling-parent-slots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly vuejs recommendations, a child component should never change it's parent, instead you can use events or vuex, and then your header will behave accordingly.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Implicit-parent-child-communication-use-with-caution